# Rails - Has many on model with multiple references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a model `CompanyIntro` which has two references to a `Company`:

```rb
class CompanyIntro < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company_one, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "company_one_id"
  belongs_to :company_two, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "company_two_id"

  ...
```

I would like to do something like:

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_intros, class_name: 'CompanyIntro', foreign_key: 'company_one_id'
  has_many :company_intros, class_name: 'CompanyIntro', foreign_key: 'company_two_id'

...
```

But this is not valid

In my `Company` model, how to I create a `has_many` for both foreign keys? I am using Rails 6 which dos not allow custom sql for `has_many` (afaik). I also do not want to write a custom `company_intros` method on the `Company` model as I'm using another gem which looks for my `has_many` relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define has_many assocations where the foreign key is one of two columns. Its just not supported by ActiveRecord as the feature would add tons of complexity.

Using the same name for two assocations also just overwrites the previous assocation. If you want to have a single assocation here you need to add a join table.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_intro_participations
  has_many :company_intros, through: :company_intro_participations
end

# for lack of a better name
class CompanyIntroParticipation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :company_intro
end

class CompanyIntro < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_intro_participations
  has_many :companies, through: :company_intro_participations
end
```

The alternative is creating a method which joins on `company_one_id = companies.id OR company_two_id = companies.id` but you will not be able to use that in the same way as an association when it comes to stuff like eager loading.

Comment: Thank you. Your response makes sense, appreciate the options you gave here.. Prior to Rails 5 you could write your own SQL for a `has_many` but that is no longer supported. Join table might make sense but I don't want to make it overly complex. Thank you!

Comment: You can still add scopes to an assocation `has_many :foos, ->{ where(bar: 'baz') }` but you can't change the join clause. This makes sense when you consider that `.joins`, `.includes` and `.eager_load` create really different queries.

Comment: If you want to find examples of how ppl have solved it the same problem pops up every time someone tries to make a facebook clone where users can like each other.